# A command showing if I have the right to perform writing?

Tags: shell-script, files, permissions

I'm searching for a command which only says if the current user has r-rights (read) on the file passed as a parameter.

This command could be something like `haveIRights -x <file>` and it has to only return explicitly yes or not.

Is there a command like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the Wooledge wiki on [tests and conditionals](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals):

> -w FILE: True if the file is writable by you.

So, you could test it with:

```
[[ -w "$file" ]]
```

If you aren't using bash, you could equally use `[ -w "$file" ]`

Comment: Using this tip (or using `find`), it is very easy to actually write a fully functional script that would satisfy the OP's needs. (This comment not made to suggest any changes, but rather encourage the OP to write a script :P)